# libgit2 get content from older commit in C++

Tags: c++, libgit2

My problem seems quite simple but I seem to be on the wrong path on this.

I want to retreive an object from an older commit. What I have is she short OID (e.g. a6bcd4) to exactly this commit. There have been several new commits since this commit has been processed.

The code for retreiving this looks like the following.

*long_branch* is pointing to master, and *path* is pointing to a file abcd/file.txt

```
git_oid oid;
git_tree *tree;
git_commit *commit;

if (git_reference_name_to_id(&oid, m_repo, long_branch.c_str())) return nullptr;

if (git_commit_lookup(&commit, m_repo, &oid)) return nullptr;
git_commit_tree(&tree, commit);

git_tree_entry *entry;
git_tree_entry_bypath(&entry, tree, path.c_str());

git_object *obj;
git_tree_entry_to_object(&obj, m_repo, entry);
```

All calls return 0 (zero), so there is no error, but what I get is always the latest (HEAD) version of this file.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `git_reference_name_to_id` gets the OID for the HEAD of the master branch now, which is why you get the HEAD of the file.

To get a specific commit from a short ID, you have to instead build the `oid` object using `git_oid_fromstrp` and then use `git_commit_lookup_prefix`.

```
git_oid_fromstrp(&oid, "a6bcd4");
git_commit_lookup_prefix(&commit, m_repo, &oid, 6);
```

The `6` is the length of your short ID.